# Zero filling null datetimes and formatting datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, filehelpers, fixed-length-record

I'm trying to write a fixed length file with FileHelpers.  A few of the fields I have are datetimes that can be null values.  If they are null values I need them to be zero filled (i.e. "00000000" instead of the date).  I tried using a custom field converter,

```
public class CustomDateConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        if (from == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return from;
    }
}
```

but the issue is I need this date in a specific format.  I can achieve the format using

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "MMddyyyy")]
```

But then I can't use my customer field converter.

Could someone please steer me straight on how I accomplish both the format conversion and zero filling the null values I might get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purposes (writing the file) the field is an eight-digit string, so treat it as such, and only use the date conversions as an intermediate step to producing an eight-digit string.

So something like this (pseudocode):

```
if date field is null
{
    return "00000000"
}
else
{
    return string of date formatted as "MMddyyyy"
}
```

Comment: If the datetime isn't null, but instead is getting set as the `DateTime.MinValue` would it make sense to do something like
`if (from.ToString() == DateTime.MinValue.ToString())
{ return "00000000"; }`

Comment: Sure -- handle whatever edge cases you need to handle.  I'd add a case like `if date field is DateTime.MinValue then return "00000000"` but there is of course more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class CustomDateConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string stringValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue) || stringValue == "00000000")
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Convert.ToDateTime(stringValue);
    }

    public override string FieldToString(object fieldValue)
    {
        return fieldValue == null ? "00000000" : ((DateTime)fieldValue).ToString("MMddyyyy");
    }
}

[FieldConverter(typeof(CustomDateConverter))]
public DateTime? MyDate;
```